# How can i change the shape of a letter?

Tags: fonts

I want to change the way the letter "Y" from `txfontsb` package appears in the main text of the document, not in `math mode`. It looks like this

[image]

and i would like to change it with

[image]

Is it possible to replace it using another font?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{txfontsb}

 \begin{document}
Υ
 \end{document}
```

Comment: In your question you typed the latin letter Y but in the code you have Υ which is U+03a5 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER UPSILON, which one do you want to change?

Comment: In my code I typed the letter "Y".The first picture of "Y" shows what I get when I run the code. I would like the letter to appear like the second picture.

Comment: I would like to change the Upsilon (U+03a5) with Y. But I dont know how. When I run the code I always get the curly Y.

Comment: actually what you typed and what is on this web page may not match. It is true that in the question you have a latin Y in the text and a Greek Upsilon in the document code, but the page is all served as utf-8 so has gone through a transformation from the iso-8859-7 input that you specified in the document. I am going to delete my other comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your MWE you have `Υ` (Upsilon) and not `Y` (Ypsilon). But you will get greek letters instead of latin ones anyway if you use `greek` as your main language.

The following MWE (with `utf8` encoding)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

XYZ

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

If I switch the languages (i.e. I opt for `english` being the main language)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

XYZ

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

If you want to keep your setup (being `greek` the main language) you can switch to `english` with `\selectlanguage`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
XYZ

\selectlanguage{greek}
XYZ

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

If you want `Y` to appear as Ypsilon when writing in Greek, you can adopt this workaround. Add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\catcode`Y=\active
\def Y{\ifmmode\char89\else\selectlanguage{english}\char89\selectlanguage{greek}\fi}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\catcode`Y=\active
\def Y{\ifmmode\char89\else\selectlanguage{english}\char89\selectlanguage{greek}\fi}

\begin{document}

Y $Y$

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to create a command to replace the greek Y with the english one in the entire document?

Comment: @mac I suggest you to use `\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}` instead of `\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}` and to use `\selectlanguage{greek}` when you want greek letters.

Comment: When writing greek, the capital letter Y is almost in every paragraph. So its difficult for me to change it manualy. My text is in greek and when I write "Y" in any language it appears only as curly greek "Y".

Comment: @mac See the edit. egreg will let us now if anything is wrong with this... :)

Comment: The edit code is correct!I should have mentioned from the beginning that my document was in greek to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: @mac Never mind. I'm happy to have solved your problem :-)